# Pinescript - Compilation error. Line 22: Value with NA type cannot be assigned to a variable that was defined without type keyword

Tags: filtering, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

```
//@version=4
study("Hesitation EMA", overlay=true)

// Inputs
length = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
hesitation = input(0.5, minval=0, maxval=1, title="Hesitation")

// Exponential Moving Average (EMA) with hesitation smoothing
hesitation_ema = ema(close, length)
smoothed_ema = nz(hesitation_ema[1])
for i = 2 to bar_index
    if abs(hesitation_ema[i] - hesitation_ema[i-1]) > hesitation * (high[i] - low[i])
        smoothed_ema := nz(hesitation_ema[i])
    else
        smoothed_ema := nz(smoothed_ema[1])
plot(smoothed_ema, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="Hesitation EMA")

// Arrows showing what the EMA trend would be without hesitation smoothing
for i = 1 to bar_index
    if hesitation_ema[i] > hesitation_ema[i-1]
        up = high
        down = na
    else if hesitation_ema[i] < hesitation_ema[i-1]
        up = na
        down = low
    else
        up = na
        down = na
    plotarrow(up, down, offset=-length)
```

I'm trying to write a control filter that plots an Exponential Moving Average (EMA) with the added feature of "hesitation smoothing". This means that the EMA line will be smoother and less prone to sudden changes, as the script will ignore small fluctuations that fall within a certain range, determined by the "hesitation" input variable. The script also plots blue arrows showing what the EMA trend would be without hesitation smoothing. and I'm getting an error which is beyond me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply define with type keyword. For example:

```cs
x = float(na)
```

or

```cs
float x = na
```

You can get more information from [here](https://quantnomad.com/faq-value-with-na-type-cannot-be-assigned-to-a-variable-that-was-defined-without-type-keyword-how-to-fix/).